# Build a cheap cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, mesos, dcos

In order to do some POCs over Mesos, Kubernetes, DC/OS and more, I would like to build a small cluster of 3-5 nodes.
I started to build a cluster via AWS, but it becomes expansive fastly.
So, I was wondering if there is a good way to build such a cluster without spending too much money on it.

Comment: Not sure what kind of POC you want to run. you can build the Kubernetes  in-house cluster using virutalbox & vagarnt.

Comment: I'm more interested about building a cluster from scratch by myself. So, do all the installation required to build a Kubernetes cluster for example and then test it with several applications

Comment: Can you provide requrements? E.g. required resources, replication, costs ($/h) etc. Best if you can share your current setup as a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a blog where the author gives a good explanation and open source code for a cheap 3 nodes HA production cluster. It's in Digitalocean but could be replicated in any similar host provider. It's too long to post everything here so check  this [link](https://5pi.de/2016/11/20/15-producation-grade-kubernetes-cluster/)

Comment: Recommendation of commercial product/services is against SO rules.

Comment: @icarus74 I may be wrong, but that's not a commercial product.  It's just a blog where the author explains how to build a cheap cluster in DO. It's open source.

Comment: it is link to a blog that provides a price for hosting and the name of a host. That sounds advertising, even if it isn't. I'm afraid that is still against SO rules. Another thing that is heavily frowned upon here is pasting links without surrounding text. In fact links may go away / become defunct. If you instead copy-n-paste only relevant information, as a summary here, while citing source as the link, it is quite acceptable. If you do so, will be happy to remove down vote.

Comment: @icarus74 edited. I think it could really help someone trying to figure out how to build a cheap cluster. It's his personal blog. Anyhow, let me know, I can just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether you want to use the Cloud or not. Alternatives that come to mind could be:

- Using Virtual Machines in your own Computer using solutions like Vagrant (as @sfgroups mentioned) or handcrafted VMs directly.
- Building a Cluster using Raspberry Pi computers.
- Look for cheaper cloud providers

In all of these cases, you could follow guides to build your cluster from scratch like https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way (note that this is meant for GCE but most of it is applicable to other systems)

Comment: Seems that it's doable https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/mesos-on-pi

Comment: @JavierSalmeron, what is Vagrant's role in this (genuinely curious) ? Why not direct use of Hypervisor with handcrafted VMs ? Perhaps if one needs to keep evolving the VMs, churning out new VMs, it might make sense, no ?

Comment: Well, actually you can use handcrafted VMs. Many people use Vagrant because it is easier to set everything running out of the box. I will improve the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DC/OS Vagrant](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant#dcos-vagrant) to spin up a local DC/OS cluster. You do need a pretty burly machine for it to work since you're basically running a full DC/OS cluster, and if you plan on testing out any data services or big workloads there, you'll need an even bigger machine. (check on the requirements)